# Getting the stack trace from the caller?

Tags: .net, vb.net, error-handling, exception

I have some simple code for writing error/warning/info messages to a text file, along with time, date, etc.

One of the common things I to write to the file is a stack trace, like this...

```
New Diagnostics.StackTrace(New Diagnostics.StackFrame(True))
```

The problem is that if I put that code in the log file handlers, I get the stack trace to that point, which may be a few calls away from the actual location of the event.

So instead, I make this a parameter of the log file, but this results in that line of code being spread all through my app, hundreds or thousands of times.

It would be much simpler if I could put that code into the logging code itself. That would also make it more portable - StackTrace only exists on Windows.

So is there some way for the code to determine the "first caller outside this object" so I can trim the call stack just to show that?

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to put your logging points?  Are you just trying to catch the stack trace at the time of your exceptions, or are you actually trying to have some kind of debug trace where you can see the process flow?

Comment: If you are trying to trace process flow, you should try to use one of the open-source libraries and not bother with writing your own.  Some examples (among many) are log4net and Elmah.

Comment: @JeffPrince More like the former, just so we can see which of the many, many places calling the log function was called, and the line numbers are very useful. Note that the libraries you mentioned, and every other one I've seen, only run on Windows, so if we ever port, I'm back here again.

Comment: Two things:  (1) if you only want to log exceptions, you can get the stack trace from a property on the Exception object; and (2) if cross-platform is a real concern, hunt around a little; there are other choices that support multiple platforms.  Stack Overflow doesn't like library recommendations for some reason, so I am hesitant to mention others.  I just don't think it is worth your time to write your own; there are lots of free options out there.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was "read the docs". The "trick" is to use the collection within the StackTrace and work backwards through the frames until you find one who's name is not that of the class you're in.